# Visual Studio Code could not authorize Git account after update

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have updated Visual Studio Code to the latest version 81.

[Latest version of Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1z7x.png)

After running a Git command to push to my private repository, the result was an "Authentication failed", so I revoked code from the GitHub application from `https://github.com/settings/applications`.

After that, I ran Git push with a fatal result - The path is referred to code version path 79, not the version I have been updating, which is 81.

[Fatal path code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hwvj.png)

Comment: Please provide the information as text, not as images. Please [edit (change)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69969024/edit) your question (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: Are you sure it is not related to the problem caused by the update to Visual Studio Code to 1.62.2 in October/November 2021? See *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes from the terminal session.

The issue can be solved by killing the currently opened terminal, and then opening a new terminal.